# MySQL: alter unique key name?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to rename "InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId" to "CompositeKey". How do I do this via SQL?

Part of my table definition:

```
UNIQUE KEY `InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId` (`InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId`,`Identifier`,`TimeStampReceived`)
```

The table is already in production. I am trying to alter the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463363/how-do-i-rename-an-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep Femi is right. it would be done like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `test`.`UniqueKeys` 

DROP INDEX `InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId`, 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `CompositeKey` (`InputOutputConfigurationServerAccountId`,
`Identifier`,`TimeStampReceived`) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support in [MySQL's ALTER syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) to rename a key. You will have to create a new composite key and drop the old one.