# RenameIndexOperation error in MVC5 while doing update-database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, migration

I have a model named Category and you can find it's definition below:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

Subcategory is my another model, which is defined in a similar way. Afterwards, I created a new controller using this model, and named the controller CategoriesController. Then I run the command: `Add-Migration Categories`, and it created this:

```
public partial class Categories : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Services", "Category_CategoryID", "dbo.Categories");
            DropIndex("dbo.Services", new[] { "Category_CategoryID" });
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Services", name: "Subcategory_SubcategoryID", newName: "SubcategoryID");
            RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Services", name: "IX_Subcategory_SubcategoryID", newName: "IX_SubcategoryID");
            AddColumn("dbo.Subcategories", "CategoryID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            CreateIndex("dbo.Subcategories", "CategoryID");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Subcategories", "CategoryID", "dbo.Categories", "CategoryID", cascadeDelete: true);
            DropColumn("dbo.Services", "Category_CategoryID");
        }



public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Services", "Category_CategoryID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Subcategories", "CategoryID", "dbo.Categories");
        DropIndex("dbo.Subcategories", new[] { "CategoryID" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Subcategories", "CategoryID");
        RenameIndex(table: "dbo.Services", name: "IX_SubcategoryID", newName: "IX_Subcategory_SubcategoryID");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Services", name: "SubcategoryID", newName: "Subcategory_SubcategoryID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Services", "Category_CategoryID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Services", "Category_CategoryID", "dbo.Categories", "CategoryID", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
}
```

Finally, in my configuration file, I added the following lines of code:

```
var categories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category { CategoryName = "Sport" },
                new Category { CategoryName = "Music" }
            };

            categories.ForEach(c => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.CategoryName, c));
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Finally, I ran the `Update-Database` command to update my database, and create a new table with this name. But unfortunately I get the error message saying `RenameIndexOperation`, and it doesn't update the database. Can someone tell me how can I solve this problem, and update my database successfully? Please also note that I used to create a lot of migrations and do a lot of database updates, then I did remove my migrations from my project. Those may be causing problem. I don't know if there is any command to reset my last migrations.

Answer (score 2):

After finding this: [How do I rename an Index in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463363/how-do-i-rename-an-index-in-mysql)
for renaming indexes in various mysql versions.

and then finding out you can alter the migrations with your own sql like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class createdbyemployeerename : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
       Sql(@"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
             ALTER TABLE tbl DROP INDEX index_name;
             ALTER TABLE tbl ADD INDEX new_index_name (indexed_column);");
    }
}
```

hope that helps.

MySql server version is 5.6 so i had to do it like above.  5.7 has a rename feature, that could be why you an me are having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.

I tried writing a drop/create index instead but that is asking for datatypes to be included, and i am unsure how to do that. (haven't looked yet)

To answer your last question you can "reset" your migration by deleting the records from the _migrationhistory table of the database you are trying to update.

When a migration starts it checks that table to know what the last migration was that was applied.  So if its empty it will run your current migration as the initial migration.