# How can I rename primary key constraint in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables with primary keys. I did not give these primary keys constraints any name. Is it possible to give them name now and how? I am using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1463363/2037090

Comment: Not index, primary key.

Comment: The name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
CHANGE COLUMN oldname newname INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT `mytable_newname_pk` PRIMARY KEY (`newname`)
```