# Why am I getting Error #1054 When I Rename a Table in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

I know there are a lot of #1054 error related questions on here but mine is simply this - 
I renamed my table in phpmyadmin (under operations) and get the error

`error  #1054 Unknown column ~oldtablename.column~ in order clause`

when I try to click on the table name to 'browse' it.

If I rename the table back it works ok but then after renaming it again I have the same problem. Why is phpmyadmin asking for an order by with the old name? 
Any help appreciated.

EDIT - 
I managed to fix it by renaming the column in question and then renaming it back.

I will leave this question open in case anyone else has the same problem (it does not appear to be documented on SO).

Although I have it working now, it doesn't really help me understand what happened. I'd still like to know if I did something wrong (renaming a table under operations) or if it was a phpmyadmin glitch.

Comment: It must be something to do with indexes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1463376/2055998

Comment: my hunch is this too, the column in question has no index though

Comment: What was the name of the naughty column?  (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)  What version of MariaDB?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.28-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution